# Is there anyway to change a mirrored (duplicate) repo back into a fork on github?

Tags: git, github

I have my repo `private-repo.git` mirrored from `public-repo.git`.

I would like to make `private-repo.git` public now and was wondering if I can rebase as a fork (as the only reason it was mirrored was to be able to have a private "fork").

I have no intention of making a PR or merging changes. There are enough nontrivial differences from the source `public-repo.git` that `private-repo.git` has diverged into it's own project, but still has significant assets and source from `public-repo.git`. An analogy might be that `private-repo.git` is Waluigi, while the source repo `public-repo.git` is Luigi.

I'd like to acknowledge the original project at any rate (beyond a mention and the stipulated license/copyright), and I believe the etiquette there is to fork `public-repo.git`.

Unless I can preserve my full commit history and git log from `private-repo.git`, I would not want to fork `public-repo.git` and just do a massive add and commit.

Any git wizards have ideas? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unless I can preserve my full commit history and git log from private-repo.git, I would not want to fork public-repo.git and just do a massive add and commit.

You could try and:

- fork public-repo.git
- push or force push (git push --force) your branches on that fork, effectively replacing the origin history of those branches by your own.

That should not make that remote repo any less of a fork.

Comment: So even commit history on private master (which includes public master history up until time of being mirrored)  can overwrite the forked master?

Comment: @Alnitak Sure: a `push --force` will do that. Since your private master does include the public one up until time of being mirrored, that part of the history will be unchanged.